# Should I consider a Maltese or English Bulldog with children (ages 3-11 years)?

Tags: dogs, pet-selection

I have smaller brothers. One have 3 years, another have 5, another 7 and another have 11 years.

What dog is better for these children? Maltese or english bulldog?

I have a small house, without garden!!!

Answer (score 5):

Even within any given breed, dogs will have varying personalities. So, "this breed works well with that range of ages" is impossible to answer, especially without knowing more about the family. A family that is outside fur running and playing for at least an hour each day will need a different dog than a stay-at-home family, after all.
You need a dog with a personality that fits well into your family. With a 3 and a 5 year old around, I would suspect you need a very patient dog above all!
Rather than seeking the fitting breed, contact a dog-rescue, and seek a dog with the right personality! Chances are, you will end up with a small- to medium-sized mix :).

Comment: I'd add its worth considering the personality of the children as well.

Answer (score 3):

### Maltese or English Bulldog

Out of the two breeds you mentioned, Maltese would be a better fit. 4 young siblings would be too much for an English Bulldog. Due to their genetic predispositions they will have a hard time keeping up as well as their difficulty to be trained will be even harder with 4 young siblings.

### What could be my other options?

Labrador Retriever and Golden Retriever will always top the list of best family dogs to have, they are energetic, easy to train and can take a beating (as in rough play with kids).

These dogs are also very content with morning and evening walks, they do not require intense work-outs like a Border Collie or Australian Cattle Dog would.

There are many ways to keep a dog happy when you don't have a back yard:

- Hire a local dog walker
- Doggy Daycare
- Dog Sports - Flyball, Disc Dog, Dock Diving
- Dog Puzzle Toys

With 4 kids, no doubt the dog would be loved and played with plenty.